# How to localize the Autodesk Forge Viewer DiffTool extension

Tags: localization, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, i18next

We are using the [Autodesk Forge Viewer DiffTool extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/difference-3d-models-autodeskdifftool-extension), but we need to change one of the texts:

[image: Screenshot with the text to be changed highlighted]

Every tutorial shows how add localization to your own extension, but I couldn't find how to change a translation in an existing extension you are using.

Moreover, without knowing what the translation key is, I would have "guess" it, which isn't really great either.

So, how do I change the translation for this text?

Comment: Is this just a one off adjustment? - i.e. is the translation wrong? In that case we can fix it on our side. Or you want to be able to adjust the translation for multiple items for some other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to hook into the translation service of the **Viewer** to change the text. If the translation is wrong, please let us know, and we can fix that on our side.

If you want to change the text for some other reasons, then one thing you could do is wait for the initialization of the extension's UI and change the button's content using DOM APIs:

```
let extensionConfig = {}
extensionConfig['mimeType'] = 'application/vnd.autodesk.revit'
extensionConfig['primaryModels'] = [model1]
extensionConfig['diffModels'] = [model2]
extensionConfig['diffMode'] =  'overlay' 
extensionConfig['versionA'] =  '2' 
extensionConfig['versionB'] =  '1' 
extensionConfig['onInitialized'] = () => {
  let button = document.getElementById("diffFacetsRemovedButton");
  let label = button.nextSibling;
  label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace("Odebrat", "Něco jiného");
}
                            
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.DiffTool', extensionConfig);
```

[image]